# Finding a balance between deprecating repos and deprecating branches

Tags: git, gitflow

(This question might be overly broad, and it certainly doesn't have a "right" answer.)

I am rewriting some small embedded projects for a company. Rather than dive into the pre-existing code, I am restarting from scratch. The original code was written by students for a research project and while it proved the point, it has deep bugs and wasn't written or maintained in a professional manner.

No complaints here, hats off to them for proving it was possible in the first place. However, it means that it doesn't make sense to try to save the original code. Much better to start from scratch and build from an agreed-upon feature list and design document.

Now that I have these new projects up and running, what is the best practice for bringing these back into the company? Should I

1. Make a commit which effectively clobbers all the old code and replaces it with mine?
2. Or should I archive the existing repo and make a new repo?

Pros for #1: Anyone who checks out the code gets the full history. If someone is looking for an old feature they can find it easily.
Cons for #1: Why would you ever think to look in the git history for this data? The original coders aren't particularly versed in git and aren't likely to think of searching for the code this way

Pros for #2: Everything is clean
Cons for #2: Keeping old archived things around builds cruft, and it's hard to know what its value is when you come across it 5 years later. Someone might even accidentally use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking I would say *never* hard delete stuff. Which is kind of what you are doing with the new repo. 'archiving' is hard, and generally people mean 'keep a copy somewhere but don't look after it'.

You have a special case, but again, 'Generally' you would expect to have to maintain version 1 AND version 2 of any software product for a change over period.

This means you may have to release a v 1.1 after you have released 2.0.

Git makes this super easy, you can tag and branch from a historical commit, make you changes and build..... As long as you have kept the commits.

If you are just making a new repo for 'neatness' then you are potentially shooting yourself in the foot if you lose the archive repo.

I would say it comes down to who has responsibility for that old code.

If its not you, then go ahead, you are making a new product, use a different name a new repo a new language. don't make a version 2.

If it is you, then either keep the repo or archive it properly with maintenance plans and the like.

Comment: Thanks! There's a lot of value to hard deleting data. Some stuff/code is just junk and actively makes life worse by keeping it around. We git people tend to be horders-- the tool makes it so easy!--, but when interfacing with normal peeps this is a non-starter. Luckily for me, there is no need to maintain v0.1, it's going the way of the dodo. The only risk is it does something better than v1.0, and we haven't realized it yet. Those odds decrease with time, so the longer we go the worse it looks to keep around old code. Doubly luckily, no one cares aside my sense of professional pride.

Comment: "there is no need to maintain v0.1" If I had a dollar.....

Comment: Heh, how true! In this case, though, it really works. All 10 prototype units which had v0.1 now have v1.0. Plus, the interns and students who wrote v0.1 are gone. And the planned v2 even has different hardware, so we really are leaving the past behind. This is also why I'm struggling for clarity, because I agree that in normal circumstances this is clear, but here I feel like I'm reaching the end of the value for hording.

Comment: at the end of the day disc space is cheap

Comment: Disk space is cheap, network time less so, and human time not at all. The balance here is when to recognize that the costs of keeping around stale code are higher than destroying it forever. Thanks for taking the time to help me think my way through it.